# WebView Proxy Problem - "Web page not available"

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-webview

I am behind a proxy and trying to load a webpage ( http://www.google.com)
 in webview ( I am using sdk 1.5). I have set the proxy for the emulator (by
going into Setting-> Wireless Controls -> Mobile Networks -> Access Point
Names -> T-Mobile). I am able to borwse a site through a browser app. But
when I load the page from web view, I get "WebPage not available error".

Comment: Hi, did you set permission for application `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - WebView = Web page not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423350/android-webview-web-page-not-available)

Answer (score 0):

Add 
`mWebView.enablePlatformNotifications(); to enable proxy in web view` in ur activity and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

in manifest file