# Web page Not Available with WebChromClient in Emulator

Tags: javascript, android, emulation, android-webview

My emulator is able to view pages on the internet using the default installed browser application.

the webpage is live:

However, I am using a short script with webView and WebChromeClient and get the error

> Web page not available

for any webpage I put in the script.

How do I get the activity to display the webpage?

[image]
code:

```
package com.example.com.android.jquery;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      private static final String LOG_TAG = "WebViewDemo";

        private WebView mWebView;

        private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.broswer);

            WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
            webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);

            mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

            mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new DemoJavaScriptInterface(), "demo");

            mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.leobee.com");
        }

        final class DemoJavaScriptInterface {

            DemoJavaScriptInterface() {
            }

            /**
             * This is not called on the UI thread. Post a runnable to invoke
             * loadUrl on the UI thread.
             */
            public void clickOnAndroid() {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:wave()");
                    }
                });

            }
        }

        /**
         * Provides a hook for calling "alert" from javascript. Useful for
         * debugging your javascript.
         */
        final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, message);
                result.confirm();
                return true;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - WebView = Web page not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423350/android-webview-web-page-not-available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your app internet use permission.

Thanks