# Custom Web Page Not Available Error in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

How Can i add custom web page not available errorin my webview. if there is no internet connection available.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U9x1.png

Comment: Please explain in detail. What you want to do?

Comment: put your webpage in asset folder...its works when no internet connection available

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - WebView = Web page not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423350/android-webview-web-page-not-available)