# Android assets webview saying web page not available

Tags: android, android-webview

Got this code from a Eudonix news reader tutorial and everything looks fine but still coming up with webpage not available, tried on emulator and device still same thing.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    webViewHome.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    setWebViewSettings();
    webViewHome.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptMenuHandler(this), "menuHandler");
    webViewHome.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/home.html");
}
```

Anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: Where do you initialise webViewHome?

Comment: Maybe even this needs INTERNET permission?

Comment: do you have the 'home.html' file in your assets folder? Does the APK actually contain it (use aapt to find out).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - WebView = Web page not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423350/android-webview-web-page-not-available)